# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mercator' of undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**update 1:**

hey I am getting undefined even though if I use CDN... can you help me cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js 
**console.log(d3.version);**

I am trying to run a d3 map which has airport animation. So I downloaded the files and ran it, but i'm not able to see the map. Can you tell me what the issue is?

Right now I am seeing an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mercator' of undefined
```

https://github.com/thtruo/30-Days-of-D3/tree/master/Project%2010%20-%20Flight%20Animation

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
      .scale(110)
      .translate([width / 2, height/ 2]);

    var path = d3.geo.path()
      .pointRadius(2)
      .projection(projection);

    var svg = d3.select(".wrapper")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("class", "main")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    // Add background for ocean color
    svg.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "background")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);
```

Comment: If using d3v4 or d3v5 d3.geo.mercator is now d3.geoMercator()

Comment: @AndrewReid hey they are using version 3 you can see the whole code here...its so confusing :( https://github.com/thtruo/30-Days-of-D3/blob/master/Project%2010%20-%20Flight%20Animation/index.html

Comment: Do you get the noted error while using v3?

Comment: Agreed, **they** are using v3, but are **you** using v3 as well? You claim you downloaded the files. d3 is not included in that repo and if you use a local copy this might well be a version issue like @AndrewReid noted. Please insert a `console.log(d3.version);` right before that line throwing the error and report what is printed to the console.

Comment: @altocumulus hey I am getting undefined even though if I use CDN... can you help me https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js

Comment: Even the link you shared in your comment says **5.7.0**.  You are using **v5**. Please re-read the topmost comment by @AndrewReid; it describes the problem and contains the answer as well. There is no `d3.geo` in v5, hence the error when trying to access a property of `undefined`. Use `d3.geoMercator` instead.

Comment: @altocumulus hey changed the code but still I am facing the undefined error....can you run the code from git and see it ----> ` var projection = d3.geoMercator()
      .scale(110)
      .translate([width / 2, height/ 2]); `

Comment: @altocumulus hey I am able to see the version but I am seeing an error like this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined at this line ---> var path = d3.geo.path()
      .pointRadius(2)
      .projection(projection);

Comment: Please take some time and read the comments and then dig into the [API docs](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md) and the [changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md). All your problems with the code can be solved with these documents alone. Furthermore, the site's consensus is to keep it to one question per post. So, please don't edit new questions into your original post and don't use comments for this purpose.

Comment: Again, there is no `d3.geo`, which, obviously, implies that there can be neither a `.mercator` nor a `.path` property! Hint: this time it's `d3.geoPath`. Just from having a short glimpse into the repo I can tell you there is more ahead: `d3.queue` is deprecated and not contained in d3 anymore. Have a look at [*"Load multiple files using the d3-fetch module"*](/q/49239474) for a way to substitute this. If you are really stuck with any point feel free to post another question, but, please, first make sure you did everything in your own reach to solve it.

Comment: @AndrewReid can you help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52599555/animate-the-planes-in-d3-js-while-i-am-able-to-display-the-planes

Comment: You haven't defined an origin or destination, and you need to use `path` not `this.path`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-frnpld?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @AndrewReid hi thanks for your reply, how did you find this number...it would be great if you explain  public origin = [-140,60];
  public destination = [-80,0];

Comment: @Andrew in this example they have shown multiple planes travelling, any idea how to achive that https://github.com/thtruo/30-Days-of-D3/tree/master/Project%2010%20-%20Flight%20Animation

Comment: I randomly chose two points with the form `[longitude,latitude]` (measured in degrees). To adopt for multiple paths you'll need to append multiple paths and append an equal number of planes (easiest to append parent groups and then add plane and route to those, then use .each() to trigger a the transition function using the group to find each route's related path): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tym2cf?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @AndrewReid can you give comments in the code so that it will be hard to understand

Comment: My example could be improved and streamlined, but as is I have broken down the thinking a bit more: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q1whsc?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @Andrew is there anyway can we show US maps and US airports alone

Comment: It would be best to modify the data source (or find new data) such that it only contains US airports (as opposed to filtering each load) - though this is less important if the airports geojson can easily be filtered by property. As it appears your data is not organized for easy filtering (there are no identifiers for each airport), you could do this spatially (eg: through a GIS program or something like mapshaper (using a clip in either) or in the browser (with d3.geoContains or other library (eg: turf.js) equivalents)).

Comment: @AndrewReid hey I reasearched but not able to do it...can you update in my stackblitz